# How to force response to be interpreted as failure by Scrapy AutoThrottle middleware

Tags: python, scrapy, throttling

I've got a situation where the endpoint I'm hitting sometimes returns an empty payload if it is overloaded.

Because the server responds with a 200 code, the AutoThrottle middleware treats it as a success and decreases the delay.

What would be the best way to stop a given response from decreasing the delay if its contents doesn't look kosher?